# Debian 5 Display resolution out of range

Tags: debian, display, xeon, graphical-user-interface

After installing Debian 5 on a Dual-Core Xeon machine, my display connected to the NVIDIA Quadro FX display card shows me an "out of range" error after the boot-up completes. I see the terminal text (login prompt) though.

This is mostly because my card is supplying a video signal of a higher resolution than 1024x768. How do I lower the resolution via the login prompt? I've installed Debian with the grub bootloader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X11/Xorg are hard to deal with at the best of times.

Now there are a couple things you can do. One would be to familiarize yourself with the [Xorg](http://ftp.x.org/pub/X11R7.0/doc/html/) and write a [new config by hand](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/x-config.html). It may not sound like much fun, but you'll be better able to handle such issues in the future.

Another option is to let dpkg re-create the [default config](http://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers) for you. You can do this by running:

> `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`

If that doesn't work out the way you'd hoped and you have the [nvidia proprietary drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) installed, you should be able to have them create a more better config that takes full advantage of your video card. The command for that is:

> `sudo nvidia-xconfig`

Now remember, in order to see **any** changes, you are going to have to restart Xorg. Depending on your distro and version, you can do this by pressing `Ctrl-Alt-Backspace`, but you'll have a guaranteed restart of Xorg by logging out. If you're level of FUD is high enough, just restart.

Good luck and I hope this helps.

PS- I recently helped my brother with this same problem. Here are some sample configs should you decide to hand-write/edit your config: [sample1](http://pastie.org/517276) [sample2](http://pastie.org/517288)

Comment: how can I install the nvidia drivers from the login prompt?

Comment: If you want to install from Debian (recommended), you can:

> `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nvidia-glx`

If you want to use the installer from NVidia's site, the instructions can be found here: ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/185.18.14/README/chapter-04-section-02.html

Comment: Just a suggestion, but you may find Ubuntu (http://ubuntu.com) to be a bit more user friendly than Debian. In fact, you *will* find it much more friendly.

Comment: I have used Ubuntu, its loaded on my laptop anyway.. but I have never faced such an error before so I'm stumped.. its still giving me the same error. I edited the Xorg file and I have downloaded the drivers for my NVIDIA Quadro FX 3400 now I need to figure out a way of how to install it using the login prompt

Answer (score 1):

You will find such info in the X.org config file : /etc/X11/xorg.conf. This file manages all graphics card info :-)

Comment: I'm in it, its totally blank any suggestion on what to do?